# Drawing a relation

Tags: relations

I am doing a past paper, and one of the question is:

> Let $A = ${$cat, dog, mouse, bird$}, and let $R$ be the binary
>   relation on $A$ given by:
>
> $R = ${($x, y$): $x$ and $y$ have no letter in common}.
>
> Draw $R$

I have a limited understanding of relations (after watching videos and reading books on reflexive, symmetric, transitive properties), but all the past papers I have ask me to draw a relation and I have no idea how where to start, and can not seem to find any simple resources. Please could someone guide me on this.

Edit (my attempt):

[image]

Comment: Put a labeled dot on paper for each of the four species, connect two by a line when they are related by $R$.

Comment: @EthanBolker Please see my edit in the OP, would a drawing like that be correct for the question?

Comment: obviously 'Bird' and 'Dog' don't satisfy our relation

Comment: Yes, it's right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{ (cat, dog), (mouse, bird), (bird, cat), (cat,mouse) \}$

Every pair has no letter in common, can you see it ?

Comment: So would my drawing in the OP (just added it now) be correct?

Comment: It isn't, 'Bird' and 'Dog' shared -d-.

Comment: Oops, my English is too bad haha. Please see updated. That drawing would be the correct answer for the question asked?

Comment: It is correct now.

Comment: Thank you. If there is one word which has a letter in common with every other word, then would the drawing just have a point with no lines to it?

Comment: Really? So if the word was "MouseDogCatBird" (as one single word), it would connect to every word? How can that be?

Comment: I'm sorry, i misunderstood you, you are right, it wouldn't connect to and other word.

Comment: Ok - thank you for your help sir!